# For Loop Variables declaration

Tags: apache-flex, mxml

How to initialize and make condition for 2 variables in single  for loop in Flex

let keep i and j are two variables

Answer (score 3):

like this:

```
            for(var i:int=0,j:int=2;i<10 && j<20;i++,j+=2){
                trace(i);
                trace(j);
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try :

```
for (var i:uint = 0, j:uint = 0; i < something, j < something_else ; i++, j++) {
   //...
}
```